# How to send MMS (SMS with attachment) in ionic native app (android & IOS)?

Tags: ionic3, native

I want to send MMS with my ionic native app I try cordova SMS plugin but it only can able to send text SMS, my requirement is to send SMS with image attachment. Can anyone help me out with this ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am also searching for same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lots of solutions finally I got the result, if anyone needed then use this [cordova plugin](https://github.com/jondspa/cordova-sms-plugin)

Thanks to jondspa.